# Error when installing mosquitto with websockets on centos 7

Tags: linux, centos7, mosquitto, libwebsockets

I have followed the next steps:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install wget mercurial cmake openssl-devel c-ares-devel libuuid-devel
wget https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/archive/v1.3-chrome37-firefox30.tar.gz
tar zxvf v1.3-chrome37-firefox30.tar.gz
cd libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30
mkdir build; cd build;
cmake .. -DLIB_SUFFIX=64
sudo make install

To install mosquitto:

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto
cd mosquitto
hg pull && hg update 1.4

In config.mk: 
  WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=yes

make binary
sudo make install
```

All goes well until the last line to install mosquitto... sudo make install
And this is what the console shows:

```
set -e; for d in lib client src; do make -C ${d}; done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib'
make -C cpp
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib/cpp'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib/cpp'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/client'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/client'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/src'
set -e; for d in lib client src; do make -C ${d} install; done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib'
make -C cpp
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib/cpp'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib/cpp'
install -d /usr/local/lib/
install -s --strip-program=strip libmosquitto.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libmosquitto.so.1
ln -sf libmosquitto.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libmosquitto.so
install -d /usr/local/include/
install mosquitto.h /usr/local/include/mosquitto.h
make -C cpp install
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib/cpp'
install -d /usr/local/lib/
install -s --strip-program=strip libmosquittopp.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libmosquittopp.so.1
ln -sf libmosquittopp.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libmosquittopp.so
install -d /usr/local/include/
install mosquittopp.h /usr/local/include/mosquittopp.h
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib/cpp'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/lib'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/client'
install -d /usr/local/bin
install -s --strip-program=strip mosquitto_pub /usr/local/bin/mosquitto_pub
install -s --strip-program=strip mosquitto_sub /usr/local/bin/mosquitto_sub
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/client'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/src'
install -d /usr/local/sbin
install -s --strip-program=strip mosquitto /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto
install mosquitto_plugin.h /usr/local/include/mosquitto_plugin.h
install -s --strip-program=strip mosquitto_passwd /usr/local/bin/mosquitto_passwd
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/src'
set -e; for d in man; do make -C ${d} install; done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/man'
install -d /usr/local/share/man/man8
install -m 644 mosquitto.8 /usr/local/share/man/man8/mosquitto.8
install: cannot stat ‘mosquitto.8’: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/investigador_uno/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30/build/mosquitto/man'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto
cd mosquitto
hg pull && hg update 1.4
```

The 1.4 branch from hg is not complete, you should you use the git repository instead: http://git.eclipse.org/c/mosquitto/org.eclipse.mosquitto.git

The problem you are seeing is related to the man pages not being built due to file locations differing from distro to distro. This is only something that is done with the unreleased code. If you download the released source instead it will be fine.